# exit php function with fatal error

Tags: php

I have a basic if-then-else statement to catch an "exception" but I can not do much in case the exception happens so I would like to exit my script at this point with a fatal error. How can I do this?
The code is:

```
if(ksort($hFileList)) $fileList = array_values($hFileList);
else ???
```

That is: I am duing all I can to ensure my $hFileList is there and looks as it should, but in case something unexpected happens, I would like to produce a standard php fatal error.
Shall I simply get rid of the if and let it "crash" instead?

Comment: @Thrustmaster: author wants _I would like to produce a standard php fatal error_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put a call to phps trigger_error method:

```
if( true === $errorCase ) {
    trigger_error( $yourErrorMessage, E_ERROR );
}
```

that'll stop your script with a fatal error.
see php documentation also:

[http://php.net/manual/de/function.trigger-error.php](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.trigger-error.php)

Comment: Note that you cannot use `E_ERROR` here. The `error_type` parameter must be one of the `E_USER` constants, so you'd have to write `E_USER_ERROR` instead of `E_ERROR` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also you [die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) function like:

```
if(ksort($hFileList)) 
{
    $fileList = array_values($hFileList);
}
else
{ 
    die("Error Occurred");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use [trigger_error(..)](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.trigger-error.php) if you do not want any exception-catching mechanisms.

You might like a more readable construct:

```
ksort($hFileList) or trigger_error("IT FAILED!",E_ERROR);
$fileList = array_values($hFileList);
```

Comment: Author wants _I would like to produce a standard php fatal error_

Comment: @neworld Ah, yes, I overlooked that part. THanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use good old [exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) function maybe?